# Why do resolutions get removed from package.json after running yarn install?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-lock.json, yarn-v3

After upgrading to yarn 3, when I run `yarn install`, the resolutions are getting removed from `package.json` and added in `yarn.lock` file.

Are resolutions not supposed to reside in `package.json` when using yarn 3?

Comment: I'm also finding that yarn 3 is automatically removing resolutions for nested packages. E.g. `x/**/y: 1.0.0`

Comment: It appears the glob syntax `**` isn't/wasn't supported. Following the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions), Yarn is happy if removing the globs - which is arguably better, be it annoying if the dependencies are highly nested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `yarn set resolution` with the newer versions of yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/resolution

Warning! To persist the changes, use the -s flag or you'll lose the custom resolution when you regenerate your yarn.lock file.

Comment: `-s` is not implemented (yet). See https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2202